# put a check on a checkbox if its values are in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, phalcon

i have these [checkboxes](https://31.media.tumblr.com/5b7dddffe3393e926bd64e48e388d5c8/tumblr_na6qdrrWBm1rdurp3o1_500.png) i can already get the value from it's table but i just don't know how it would end up on checking those check boxes with values that are already inserted in my database.

```
 function editPageLink(id){  
    $.ajax({
        type    : 'GET',
        async   : false,  
        data    : {
            key : id
        },
        url     : baseUrl+'/admin/getdiscountinfo',
        error: function(req,error){ 
                    notify('e',req.statusText);
                },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success : function(msg){    
            if(Object.keys(msg).length != 0){ 
                newPage();
                saveType = 'u';
                key = msg[0].key;
                $('#discountCode').val(msg[0].discountCode);
                $('#discountName').val(msg[0].discountName);
                $('#discountDesc').val(msg[0].discountDesc);
                $('#discountType').val(msg[0].discountType);
                $('#expiration').val(msg[0].expiration);
                $('#expStartDate').val(msg[0].expStartDate);
                $('#expEndDate').val(msg[0].expEndDate);
                $('#discountValue').val(msg[0].discountValue);
                $('#productId').val(msg[0].productId); if ('.chkbox2'.val() == true){
                    $('.chkbox2').check(checked); // i dunno if this is right.
                };
                $('#discounteTransaction').val(msg[0].discountTransaction);
            }
        }
    });
```

}

i tried it but it's still not working. thanks for your help! :D

**EDIT** : my `#productId` and `'.chkbox2'` are the same. is this part, getting the value is right ?

```
 $('#productId').val(msg[0].productId); if ('.chkbox2'.val() == true){
    $('.chkbox2').check(checked);
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah! finally. i solved it i just changed

```
$('#productId').val(msg[0].productId); if ('.chkbox2'.val() == true){
                $('.chkbox2').check(checked); // i dunno if this is right.
            };
```

to

```
$('.chkbox2').val(msg[0].productId,':checked',true);
```

yehet ohorat! haha thanks for your comments i earned ideas :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.chkbox2').check(checked); // i dunno if this is right.
```

A standard method of checking checkboxes in jQuery is to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$('.chkbox2').prop('checked', bool);
```

Where if `bool` = true, the checkbox will be checked. (Alternatevely, if `bool` is false, it will be unchecked)

You may also retrieve the current checked status by simply omitting the second argument:

```
$('.chkbox2').prop('checked'); // Returns true or false.
```

Additionally, in your if condition, you have an error:

```
if ('.chkbox2'.val() == true){
```

Should be

```
if( $('.chkbox2').val() == true )
```

As you're missing the jQuery wrapper for your selector.

Comment: Can you test to make sure your success callback is being executed & the data coming back from it is valid? Also, your condition reads as "If this check box has a value, do this.." Is that correct?

Comment: ahm err..  `"If this check box has a value, do this.."` actually that condition, i made it to check if my checkboxes value is already inserted in my db. and i don't know if that condition is correct. sorry sir

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.chkbox2').prop('checked', true);
```

use this to check the check box

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.chkbox2').prop('checked', true);
```

Above code will set the checkbox as checked

```
$('.chkbox2').prop('checked', false);
```

Above code will untick the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your code :D

```
$('.chkbox2').val(msg[0].productId,':checked',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#checkbox').attr('checked')

$('#checkbox').prop('checked') // true

$('#checkbox').is(':checked')  // true

$('#checkbox')[0].checked      // true